# Product url_keys nulled after some time

Tags: magento2, url, url-key

Setup: Magento 2.2.x, OpenSouce (**Magento Community Edition**)

Products were imported from Magento 1,

- url_path attributes were cleared
- all url_key values are unique (both products & categories)

After 48.0h, some of product url_keys gets nulled (`NULL` value in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`), without ANY operations done by the Client.

Has anyone experienced such issue before?

Comment: I have someone this keeps happening to as well. It's really difficult to track. Can you let me know what third party modules you have installed? I think its coming from a specific module and if any of yours overlap with ours then it could be a really good clue

Comment: I've figured it out, it is actually an issue with working on product collection and saving a product model from collection object.

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
                    try {
                        [...]
                        $product->save();
                    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                        $message = sprintf(self::UPDATE_ERROR_PATTERN, $exception->getMessage(), $product->getSku());
                        $this->helper->logError($message);
                    }
                }

work on product model / product repository

Comment: Ah yes, I could see how that could happen. If you're doing a full save but the collection isn't loading all attributes you could lose data that way.